# Texture paint won't change color

Tags: modeling, uv, texture-painting

I'm trying to use texture paint, and everything's working except the color is stuck as black. Can't figure out what's wrong, especially because it was working like an hour ago and now it's not.

If you can help let me know. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Could be uv issue but needs more details

Comment: could you please share your file (or a part of it)? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/